# about power bi dax transition: dose only the current table columns will be transformed to filter context

Tags: powerbi

I have a 4 tables:

1. Dim_Calendar  (date, year-name, month-name)
2. Generator Rooms (name)
3. monthly costs of the server (date, server-id, Generator Room Name, cost)
4. monthly costs of the Generator Rooms(date, Generator Room Name, cost)

the model is as below:

- Dim_Calendar[Date] 1:n monthly costs of the Generator Rooms[date]
- Dim_Calendar[Date] 1:n monthly costs of the server[date]
- Generator Rooms[name] 1:n monthly costs of the Generator Rooms[Generator Room Name]
- Generator Rooms[name] 1:n monthly costs of the server[Generator Room Name]

then I create a calculated column on table `monthly costs of the server` :

```
Generator Room Cost = [room cost]
```

and the measure is

```
[room cost] = SUM('monthly costs of the Generator Rooms'[cost])
```

then the calculated column of every row in the table `monthly costs of the server` is filtered by the room name and date, as I read from the book, the row context is with the table columns, and the columns in the table `monthly costs of the server` cannot filter the data in the table `monthly costs of the Generator Rooms`.

I don't know why

read the book about the chapter row context transition

Answer (score 0):

Calculated columns are static. You can filter them, but they don't recalculate on filter changes.